# Duplicate or Missing Dependency Picklist values

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting duplicate or missing picklist values.  These are dependent picklist fields. I have attached the Controller and VF page for review. If someone can let me know if this is an issue with the Controller or the VF it would be appreciated.

Controller

```
public class MerchandisingController {  

    public string Merchandise{ get; set; }
    public string Category{ get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }

    public MerchandisingController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        Merchandise= Category= SubCategory;    
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getListMerch() 
     {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption> { new SelectOption('','-- Choose Merchandise --') };
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry pe:Merchandising__c.Merchandise__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(pe.getValue(),pe.getLabel()));
        }
        return options;
    }

     public List<SelectOption> getListCategory() 
     {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(Merchandise == null || Merchandise == '')
            return options;
        options.add(new SelectOption('','-- Choose Category --'));
        for(Merchandising__c cat:[select Merchandise_Category__c from Merchandising__c where Merchandise__c= :Merchandise]) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(cat.id,cat.Merchandise_Category__c ));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getListSubCategory() 
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(Category==null || Category== '')
            return options;
        options.add(new SelectOption('','-- Choose SubCategory --'));
        for(Merchandising__c sub:[select id,Merchandise_SubCategory__c from Merchandising__c where Merchandise_Category__c = :Category]) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(sub.id,sub.Merchandise_SubCategory__c));
        }
        return options;
    }

 }
```

VisualForce Page

```
<apex:page standardstylesheets="true" showheader="false" standardController="Account" extensions="MerchandisingController" >

<div style="background-color:orange;height:150px;width:375px;">
  <apex:form id="Merchandising">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Choose Merchandizing"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Demo Page">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Merchandise</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:selectList size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!Merchandise}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListMerch}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport reRender="Merchandising" event="onchange"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Category</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:selectList value="{!Category}" size="1" multiselect="false">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListCategory}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport reRender="Merchandising" event="onchange"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >SubCategory</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:selectList value="{!SubCategory}" size="1" multiselect="false">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListSubCategory}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport reRender="Merchandising" event="onchange"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than build preparing picklist values through `SelectOption` and using them as `apex:selectList`, you could use `apex:inputField` for picklist fields in VFP.

Automatically, dependency will be applied to the dependent fields properly.